# few short question about branch-cut and branch points

Tags: complex-analysis

> Q. Find branch points and construct branch lines for the functions
>   $\displaystyle (a)  f(z) = \left( \frac{z}{1-z} \right)^{\frac 1 2 } $
>   $\displaystyle (b) \left( z^2  - 4\right)^{\frac 1 3 } $
>   $\displaystyle (c) f(z) = \ln (z-z^2)$

(I am guessing) For $(a)$  the branch point is $0$ and $\infty$ and the branch like will be any straight line extending from $0$ to $\infty$, for $(b)$ the branch points are $\pm 2$ and branch line would be a line joining these two points, and for $(c)$ the branch point are $0$ and $1$ and I don't know how to draw branch line here.

Comment: I have no time for a proper answer, but your guess for (a) isn't right: Notice that the fraction goes to $-1$ at infinity, so that is not a problem from a branching point of view. $z=1$, on the other hand, …

Comment: so $z=1$ is the branch point?

Comment: Yes, and $z=0$ also. As for (b) and (c), watch out for infinity. Think about what happens when $|z|$ is very large: In (b) you almost get $z^{4/3}$, and in (c) you almost get $\ln(-z^2)$. (For “almost” read “asymptotically”, really.)

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track! Here’s a bit more detail:
(a) For f(z)=z(1−z)​
, the branch points are indeed at 0 and 1. The branch cut can be any curve connecting these two points. A common choice is the straight line from 0 to 1 on the real axis.
(b) For f(z)=(z2−4)1/3
, the branch points are at z = ±2. Again, the branch cut can be any curve connecting these two points, and a common choice is the straight line from -2 to 2 on the real axis.
(c) For f(z)=ln(z−z2)
, the branch points are at 0 and 1. The branch cut is a bit trickier here because it needs to start at 0, end at 1, and not pass through the point at infinity. A common choice is to use two branch cuts: one from 0 to -∞ along the negative real axis, and another from 1 to +∞ along the positive real axis. This way, the cuts do not cross, and all branch points are connected to ∞.
Remember, the choice of branch cuts can often be arbitrary and may depend on the specific problem or context. The important thing is that they connect the branch points and do not cross each other.